# Are the Sefiros round?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah

I heard from someone many years ago that that the Sefiros are round somehow. I was wondering if there are any authentic sources in kabalah? I realize they are not physical things but nevertheless is there such a source?

Comment: What would be the implications of the roundness of the Sefiros?

Comment: Why not ask of they're blue?

Comment: If you can start with the understanding that they are not physical why would there be any sense of shape to them? Have you seen anything written about them that uses the language of physicality and you want to know if that is metaphorical, or literal?

Comment: @rosends i heard this from someone many years ago and was wondering if there is such a source.

Answer (score 1):

Avinoam Frankel recently published a translation and significantly annotated version of the Sefer Shomer Emunim by Rabbi Yosef Ergas. The book also contains a “Kabbalah Overview”. There Rabbi Frankel discusses two different configuration schemes of the sefirot: Igulim (circles) and Yosher (upright/straight). See pg 660 section 3.

Comment: that is something else. thank you

Answer (score -1):

The sefiros do not have a shape. you are trying to apply physical characteristics to things that aren't physical. we only speak of the sefiros in terms that we can understand. since humans can only relate to the physical we speak in physical terms but this does not mean they have any shape, form, or anything physical about them. the sefiros are concepts